# Vaadin 7 with websockets

Tags: java, atmosphere, vaadin7

I have a vaadin 7.1.4 web application which displays the backend data in various UI structures (Table, Tree). It deals with a lot of data and hence it's multi-threaded. It's currently running in Tomcat 6 server.

I am looking for a way to implement websockets in my application to perform some very specific task. The task is explained graphically in the following image:

[image: Vaadin application design]

I am looking for a way to do this. Please help me to solve the following questions:

1. Which framework should I use to create the websocket server and client?
2. Is there a atmosphere java client which can be integrated with vaadin?
3. Can I use Vaadin's push framework to solve this problem?

I did my homework and I found out that atmosphere framework (which is also used in Vaadin) is a close contestant. But the examples deal with JavaScript clients instead of Java clients.

Answer (score 5):

While I am familiar with Vaadin 6 & 7, I'm not an expert on WebSocket. So take what I have to say with a grain of salt. But here goes…

(a) Your drawing suggests that you have a focus on the client (browser) side. You might need to shift your thinking. The main point of Vaadin is that the app actually runs on the server. While we conceptually think of our app as running in front of the user, we know the app’s state and execution actually live on the server. We do not usually think in terms of what is literally going on inside the web browser.

This is what makes Vaadin so special, and not one of the many *yet-another-web-framework* projects. As far as I know, Vaadin is nearly unique in this regard. The only other web app kit with a server-side-execution architecture like Vaadin is the (non-Java) [Xojo](http://www.xojo.com/), Web Edition (formerly known as Real Studio).

(b) Seems like what you really want is called "push", without concerning yourself with WebSocket details. To explain…

### React To User

Normally a Vaadin app waits to respond to a user's action, such as typing in a field or clicking a button.

When the user clicks a button in the browser, for example, the Vaadin framework installed browser-side automatically notifies the Vaadin app running on the server of that user's action. The server-side app then runs some code attached to the button. That pure-Java code is running on the server. Say the button updates the text in a field. When your server-side code updates the text value, the Vaadin server-side framework automatically notifies the browser-side Vaadin framework of the new value. The new value automatically appears on screen for the user to see.

Note that we as Vaadin programmers do not concern ourselves with the nitty-gritty details of the back-and-forth that just happened in the scenario above. The browser-server interaction may have been performed with HTTP request-responses, with long-polling, or with WebSocket, or with who knows what all. We don’t care. That Vaadin 7.1 happens to be using the [Atmosphere framework](https://github.com/Atmosphere) as part of its implementation is not (usually) any of our concern. That's the power, and special distinction, of Vaadin.

### Push

Sometimes a programmer would like to update the display seen by the user without waiting for the user to take an action.

Perhaps the data being displayed in a report to the user is changing. The programmer might want her app to be so slick as to automatically update the report without the user having to bother clicking an *Update* button. This behavior is called "push", as in *pushing* updates to the user's screen. The Vaadin blog posting, [Roadmap for the next 74 days](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/roadmap-for-the-next-74-days), explains that a major innovation of Vaadin 7.1 is support for push.

In Vaadin 6, some folks used add-ons (plugins) to gain some push features. But given that Vaadin 6 was not architected with that in mind, there were limitations.

### Focus on Push

So, WebSockets is one way of getting push, but not the only way. Focus your attention on the "push" features. Let Vaadin do the worrying about whether it should use WebSockets with Atmosphere or some other technology du jour.

Read the [Server Push](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html) chapter in [The Book of Vaadin](https://www.vaadin.com/book). That may be all you need to get started.

---

As a Vaadin programmer, you should not have to care about WebSocket. But as a system administrator, you should be very excited about WebSocket. This technology promises an enormous increase in the speed, responsiveness, and robustness of the app. Caveat: This technology is new, so we do not yet know how it performs in the real world. Given the promise, and the availability of Vaadin 7.1, you may want to enable your [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) container with WebSocket support.

[JSR-356 Java WebSocket](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356) this year (2013) defined a standard interface for the WebSocket protocol defined by [IETF rfc 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

Apache [Tomcat 8](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi) innovated an implementation of that JSR. That implementation has been backported to [Tomcat 7.0.47](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html), deprecating the Apache Tomcat proprietary WebSocket API in favor of the new JSR-356 implementation. Tomcat 8 is at release-candidate stage, so you may want to try it, though I don't know what may work best with Vaadin 7.1.

Eclipse [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) also [supports WebSocket](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/WebSockets). Jetty compares closely to Tomcat, both work very well in general (though I cannot speak to their WebSocket features).

[Other Servlet containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Servlet_containers) may offer support for WebSocket.

**UPDATE:** Pay attention to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20149068/642706) by [jfarcand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044473/jfarcand). I just noticed that he (Jean‑François Arcand) is the creator of [the Atmosphere framework](http://async-io.org/release.html)!

**UPDATE 2015-10:** The Servlet containers such as [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) & [Eclipse Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) have been iterating many releases for fixes and improvements for WebSocket. Be sure to update to later versions. Ditto for Vaadin, many iterations include fixes to WebSocket, [currently](https://vaadin.com/download) 7.5.8.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 2):

answering your questions:

> Which framework should I use to create the websocket server and client?

I recommend you use Vaadin 7.1.x which use Atmosphere under the hood. You can also use Atmosphere directly, but I must say the integration with Vaadin is quite good. Atmosphere runs everywhere websockets is supported: Vert.x, Play! Servlet and Netty.

> > > Is there a atmosphere java client which can be integrated with vaadin?

Yes, see [wAsync](https://github.com/Atmosphere/wasync)

> > Can I use Vaadin's push framework to solve this problem?

Yes